# Indent a block of code on the basis of a single character

Tags: vim

The question's title might sound a little vague, so I'll explain the situation here more clearly.
I have these lines of code in a file which I want to align with respect to the character `=`.

```
const service = require('./service');
const baseService = require('./baseService');
const config = require('../config');
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const errors = require('../errors');
```

I want the above lines to somehow look like this

```
const service     = require('./service');
const baseService = require('./baseService');
const config      = require('../config');
const Promise     = require('bluebird');
const errors      = require('../errors');
```

I want all the `=` characters to lie in the same column and shift the after-coming code accordingly. What can I do to achieve this task?

A plugin capable of doing this would be nice, but it'd be great if I could do this without the aid of any plugin. That way I'd also learn something.

Comment: Duplicate of https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/20658/18609

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using GNU tools

```
 :%!column -t -s= -o=      

  % ............. current file
  ! ............. use external command
 -t ............. use tabs
 -s ............. input separator
 -o ............. output separator
```

Instead of whole file it can be a range of lines `1,5` or you can select a paragraph with `vip`

I ended up creating a function called AlignText that uses column command to solve this issue:

```
" Align text by a chosen char
" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57093175/
" https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2412/7339
if !exists('*AlignText')
    function! AlignText(param) range
        execute a:firstline . ',' . a:lastline . '!column -t -s' . a:param . ' -o' . a:param
    endfunction
endif
command! -range=% -nargs=1 Align <line1>,<line2>call AlignText(<q-args>)
" :Align =
" :8,$ Align =
```

If you wnat to test this function before put it into your vimrc, copy the code to your clipboard and then try this:

```
:@+
```

Now you can use something like this:

```
:15,22Align /
:Align ,
```

I by any change you want to use the function call instead of the command one, don't forget to pass the range and put the argument between quotes.

A slitly different version that accepts nor arguments and uses just "column -t"

```
" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57093175/
" https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2412/7339
function! AlignText(...) range
    if a:0 < 1
        execute a:firstline . ',' . a:lastline . '!column -t'
    else
        execute a:firstline . ',' . a:lastline . '!column -t -s' . a:1 . ' -o' . a:1
    endif
endfunction
command! -range=% -nargs=? Align <line1>,<line2>call AlignText(<f-args>)
```

Answer (score 4):

there are plugins can do this kind of alignment. E.g.

Align or easy-align. I have been using Align for a long time, for your requirement, I just select those lines and do `<leader>t=`

https://github.com/vim-scripts/Align

https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align

You can of course code by yourself, you find out the max length before the `=`, then you know how many spaces you should insert between `partBefore` and `=`. (the diff) on each line.

Comment: @KartikChauhan the last paragraph explained shortly how can you implement the function ("native").

Answer (score 1):

(**NOTE:** Originally [answered](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/20670/18609) at the [Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/).)

If you're in a pinch and want to get the expressions aligned, without having to install and learn any plug-ins, here is a quick way to do it.

1. Select the lines on a visual selection. For example, if this is your whole buffer, you could use `ggVG`, but if these lines are in the middle of a file, just select appropriately. Perhaps `V4j`?
2. Insert enough whitespace before the `=`, which you can do with `:normal f=9i` . (Note the "space" at the end.) This will add 9 spaces before each `=` in the lines of the visual selection. If 9 is not enough, add more (like 99 or 999, as much as you want.) Note that when you type `:` with the visual selection, Vim will automatically insert the range, so the actual command is `:'<,'>normal f=9i` , but you don't need to type those characters.
3. Move to the column where you want the `=`s to be flushed to. In this case, line 2 has the longest variable name, so move to two spaces after the end of that name, which is where the `=`s should be at the end. If this is the whole buffer, you could use `2G2e2l` to get there.
4. Staying on that same column, move to the first line of the block. In this case, you're moving from line 2 to line 1, so `k` is enough.
5. Start visual-block selection, pressing `Ctrl-V`.
6. Move to the last line of the block. If this is the whole buffer, you could use `G`, if this is the middle of a file, you could use `4j` to go four lines down, etc.
7. (Optional) Use `$` to select until the end of the line, on *every* line of the visual block selection. **UPDATE:** This step is actually not necessary here, since `<` will work correctly even if you don't select lines to the end. Using `$` is important when using e.g. `A` to append to the end of all lines though.
8. Now you can use the `<` command to shift the lines left, but until they hit the left of the visual block. Each `<` will shift them by one `'shiftwidth'` only, so you're likely to need more than one. So, to be sure, use `9<` (or `99<`, or `999<`, if you added tons of spaces in step 2.)

*Voilà!*

This is a pretty cool technique and it can be helpful when you need more flexibility than plug-ins can afford you. It's a good one to learn and keep on your Vim toolbox.