# How to organize columns in vim?

Tags: vim

I got some columns that look like this:

```
9  normal    tri key     __tri_key
26 32     throw ex   __throw_ex
42 normal     row lend     __row_lend
98 normal   race car    __race_car
101 32      math chk      __math_chk
```

How can I make them like this (via command of course).

```
9     normal    tri key     __tri_key
26    32        throw ex    __throw_ex
42    normal    row lend    __row_lend
98    normal    race car    __race_car
101   32        math chk    __math_chk
```

Comment: In your example you have spaces as both field separator and "normal" space. So it could be hard to pack all functionality into a general purpose command. Anyway, check [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/20658/align-a-block-of-code-on-the-basis-of-a-single-character).

Comment: Yes, definitely check out the answer to the question @Matt linked to! 

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+columns

Comment: @Matt can we assume that the field separator is a tab ;)?

Comment: actual keystrokes: V}!column -t<cr>

Answer (score 0):

I have a function called **AlignText** that works like if you were using the "column" command. If you pass a separator it will use it as separator, if not it will function like normal column command.

```
" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57093175/
" https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2410/
if !exists('*AlignText')
    function! AlignText(...) range
        if a:0 < 1
            execute a:firstline . ',' . a:lastline . '!column -t'

        else
            execute a:firstline . ',' . a:lastline . '!column -t -s' . a:1 . ' -o' . a:1
        endif
    endfunction
endif
command! -range=% -nargs=? Align <line1>,<line2>call AlignText(<f-args>)
```

If you select a portion it will work on that if not the whole file will be changed

```
vip ........................... visual inner paragraph
:'<,'>Align ................... apply change on selected paragraph
```

You can copy the function and the "command!" to the clipboard and run on vim:

```
:@+ ....................... will put the function into vim memory
vip ....................... select your block of text
:'<,'>Align ............... voila, text aligned
```

The actual "column" command can be used this way:

```
vip ....................... select the paragraph
:'<,'>!column -t
```

Answer (score 0):

For alignment, there are three well-known plugins:

- the venerable [Align - Help folks to align text, eqns, declarations, tables, etc](https://www.vim.org/script.php?script_id=294)
- the modern [tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular)
- the contender [vim-easy-align](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4520)